# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen erwünscht und gewünscht?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, verb-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen erwünscht und gewünscht?

z.B.

> Ich weiß nicht, ob das was ich mache vom AG gewünscht ist.

> Ich weiß nicht, ob das was ich mache vom AG erwünscht ist.

Danke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Grenzen sind hier sehr verwaschen.

"Erwünscht" ist sehr förmlich und bedeutet eigentlich "notwendig", "gefordert" oder sogar "erzwungen".
"Gewünscht" ist nicht so hart und zeigt nur einen Wunsch an, dass es schön so wäre.

Allerdings ist es oft eine Frage der Situation, wie beide Wörter verwendet werden. Jemand kann aus Höflichkeit sagen, dass es "gewünscht" ist, aber meint eigentlich "erwünscht". Und es ist auch möglich, dass man "erwünscht" verwendet, damit es förmlicher und hochgestochener klingt, aber genaugenommen doch damit nur einen Wunsch hat, der keinen Zwang darstellt.